# Loading binary data with FixedLengthRecordDataset in TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to figure out how to load binary data file using `FixedLengthRecordDataset`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import struct
import numpy as np

RAW_N = 2 + 20*20 + 1

def convert_binary_to_float_array(register):
    return struct.unpack('f'*RAW_N, register.numpy())

raw_dataset = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(filenames=['mydata.bin'],record_bytes=RAW_N*4)
float_ds = raw_dataset.map(map_func=convert_binary_to_float_array)
```

This code throws:

```
AttributeError: in user code:

tf-load-data.py:14 convert_binary_to_float_array  *
    return struct.unpack('f'*RAW_N, register.numpy())

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

`numpy()` is available if I try to iterate over the dataset:

```
raw_dataset = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(filenames=['mydata.bin'],record_bytes=RAW_N*4)

for register in raw_dataset:
    print(struct.unpack('f'*RAW_N, register.numpy()))
```

By reading the [Tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) type description, I realized that `numpy()` is available only during eager execution. Thus, I can deduce that during the `map()` call the elements are not provided as `EagerTensor`.

How to load this data into a dataset?

I'm using TensorFlow 2.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest working with [tf.io.decode_raw](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_raw). I unfortunately do not know what `mydata.bin` looks like so I created some dummy data:

```py
import random
import struct
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

RAW_N = 2 + 20*20 + 1

bytess = random.sample(range(1, 5000), RAW_N*4)
with open('mydata.bin', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(struct.pack('1612i', *bytess))

def convert_binary_to_float_array(register):
    return tf.io.decode_raw(register, out_type=tf.float32)

raw_dataset = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(filenames=['/content/mydata.bin'], record_bytes=RAW_N*4)
raw_dataset = raw_dataset.map(convert_binary_to_float_array)

for register in raw_dataset:
  print(register)
```

You could also try first decoding your data into integers with `tf.io.decode_raw` and then casting to float with `tf.cast`, but I am not sure if it will make a difference.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting to slice the dataset. The resulting dataset is a MapDataset and I cannot even call tf.shape on it. Do you can suggest an example of end-to-end use of binary data in tensorflow?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean. Could you post a new question with these details?

Comment: can you check my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70657656/3055724