# spliting custom binary dataset in train/test subsets using tensorflow io

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use local binary data to train a network to perform [regression inference](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression).

Each local binary data has the following layout:

[image]

and the whole data consists of several *.bin files with the layout above. Each file has a variable number of sequences of 403*4 bytes. I was able to read one of those files using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

RAW_N = 2 + 20*20 + 1

def convert_binary_to_float_array(register):
     return tf.io.decode_raw(register, out_type=tf.float32)

raw_dataset = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(filenames=['mydata.bin'],record_bytes=RAW_N*4)
raw_dataset = raw_dataset.map(map_func=convert_binary_to_float_array)
```

Now, I need to create 4 datasets `train_data`, `train_labels`, `test_data`, `test_labels` as follows:

```
train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels = prepare_ds(raw_dataset, 0.8)
```

and use them to train & evaluate:

```
model = build_model()

history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, ...)

loss, mse = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)
```

My question is: how to implement function `prepare_ds(dataset, frac)`?

```
def prepare_ds(dataset, frac):
    ...
```

I have tried to use `tf.shape`, `tf.reshape`, `tf.slice`, subscription [:] with no success. I realized that those functions doesn't work properly because after the `map()` call `raw_dataset` is a `MapDataset` (as a result of the eager execution concerns).

Comment: What are your labels? You can use ds.take(*) and ds.skip(*)

Comment: @AloneTogether the label is a number between 0 and 1 such as 0.255 or 0.79. This is the outcome I need to perform regression (no classification).

Comment: I'm not sure if `tf.data.Dataset.skip()` may be helpful. I don't want to skip elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the meta-data is suppose to be part of your inputs, which I am assuming, you could try something like this:

```py
import random
import struct
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

RAW_N = 2 + 20*20 + 1

bytess = random.sample(range(1, 5000), RAW_N*4)
with open('mydata.bin', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(struct.pack('1612i', *bytess))

def decode_and_prepare(register):
  register = tf.io.decode_raw(register, out_type=tf.float32)
  inputs = register[:402]
  label = register[402:]
  return inputs, label

total_data_entries = 8
raw_dataset = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(filenames=['/content/mydata.bin', '/content/mydata.bin'], record_bytes=RAW_N*4)
raw_dataset = raw_dataset.map(decode_and_prepare)
raw_dataset = raw_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=total_data_entries)

train_ds_size = int(0.8 * total_data_entries)
test_ds_size = int(0.2 * total_data_entries)

train_ds = raw_dataset.take(train_ds_size)
remaining_data = raw_dataset.skip(train_ds_size)  
test_ds = remaining_data.take(test_ds_size)
```

Note that I am using the same bin file twice for demonstration purposes. After running that code snippet, you could feed the datasets to your model like this:

```py
model = build_model()

history = model.fit(train_ds, ...)

loss, mse = model.evaluate(test_ds)
```

as each dataset contains the inputs and the corresponding labels.

Comment: Hi Thanks! I skipped the metadata by setting `inputs = register[2:402]` and I used `tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert` to get rid of a WARNING `AutoGraph could not transform function decode_and_prepare and will run it as-is`

Comment: Cool. The answer works for you?

Comment: But now my problem is with line `total_data_entries = 8`. Files has a variable number of entries. I tried `total_data_entries = len(raw_dataset)` but I got `TypeError: dataset length is unknown.`  Any ideas?

Comment: Kindly check this answer and see if it is useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535683/extract-data-from-tensorflow-dataset-e-g-to-numpy/70584413#70584413. One suggestion in my answer there would be simply: `total_data_entries = len(list(raw_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (x, y))))` after the line `raw_dataset = raw_dataset.map(decode_and_prepare)`

Comment: Thanks again. I checked here and this actually worked. Another approach I tested here was sum up the binary files size and divide it by 403*4.

Comment: AloneTogether I will appreciate if you can check my new question about tensorflow datasets: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70686756/3055724

Comment: Ok, no problem will do.