# Tensorflow tf.data.Dataset.cache seems do not take the expected effect

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to improve my model training performance following the [Better performance with the tf.data API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance) guideline. However, I have observed that the performance using `.cache()` is almost the same or even worse if compared to same settings without `.cache()`.

```
datafile_list = load_my_files()
RAW_BYTES = 403*4
BATCH_SIZE = 32

raw_dataset = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(filenames=datafile_list, record_bytes=RAW_BYTES, num_parallel_reads=10, buffer_size=1024*RAW_BYTES)
raw_dataset = raw_dataset.map(tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert(decode_and_prepare),
    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
raw_dataset = raw_dataset.cache()
raw_dataset = raw_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024)
raw_dataset = raw_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
raw_dataset = raw_dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

The data in `datafile_list` hold 9.92GB which fairly fits the system total physical RAM available (100GB). System swap is disabled.

By training the model using the dataset:

```
model = build_model()
model.fit(raw_dataset, epochs=5, verbose=2)
```

results in:

```
Epoch 1/5
206247/206247 - 126s - loss: 0.0043 - mae: 0.0494 - mse: 0.0043
Epoch 2/5
206247/206247 - 125s - loss: 0.0029 - mae: 0.0415 - mse: 0.0029
Epoch 3/5
206247/206247 - 129s - loss: 0.0027 - mae: 0.0397 - mse: 0.0027
Epoch 4/5
206247/206247 - 125s - loss: 0.0025 - mae: 0.0386 - mse: 0.0025
Epoch 5/5
206247/206247 - 125s - loss: 0.0024 - mae: 0.0379 - mse: 0.0024
```

This result is frustrating. By the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache):

> The first time the dataset is iterated over, its elements will be cached either in the specified file or in memory. Subsequent iterations will use the cached data.

And from [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/performances#caching_the_dataset):

> When iterating over this dataset, the second iteration will be much faster than the first one thanks to the caching.

However, the elapsed time took by all epochs are almost the same. In addition, during the training both CPU and GPU usage are very low (see images below).

By commenting out the line `raw_dataset = raw_dataset.cache()` the results do not show any notable difference:

```
Epoch 1/5
206067/206067 - 129s - loss: 0.0042 - mae: 0.0492 - mse: 0.0042
Epoch 2/5
206067/206067 - 127s - loss: 0.0028 - mae: 0.0412 - mse: 0.0028
Epoch 3/5
206067/206067 - 134s - loss: 0.0026 - mae: 0.0393 - mse: 0.0026
Epoch 4/5
206067/206067 - 127s - loss: 0.0024 - mae: 0.0383 - mse: 0.0024
Epoch 5/5
206067/206067 - 126s - loss: 0.0023 - mae: 0.0376 - mse: 0.0023
```

As pointed out in the docs, my expectations were using cache would result in a much fast training time. I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

**Attachments**

GPU usage during training using cache:

[image]

GPU usage during training WITHOUT cache:

[image]

System Stats (Memory, CPU etc) during training using cache:

[image]

System Stats (Memory, CPU etc) during training WITHOUT cache:

[image]

Comment: `cache` will only make a difference if reading and processing the data is a bottleneck for training. If the data is already provided to the model quickly enough without caching, it won't make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a small observation using Google Colab. According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=nightly#cache):

> Note: For the cache to be finalized, the input dataset must be iterated through in its entirety. Otherwise, subsequent iterations will not use cached data.

And

> Note: cache will produce exactly the same elements during each
> iteration through the dataset. If you wish to randomize the iteration
> order, make sure to call shuffle after calling cache.

I did notice a few differences when using caching and iterating over the dataset beforehand. Here is an example.

**Prepare data**:

```
import random
import struct
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

RAW_N = 2 + 20*20 + 1

bytess = random.sample(range(1, 5000), RAW_N*4)
with open('mydata.bin', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(struct.pack('1612i', *bytess))
def decode_and_prepare(register):
  register = tf.io.decode_raw(register, out_type=tf.float32)
  inputs = register[2:402]
  label = tf.random.uniform(()) + register[402:]
  return inputs, label

raw_dataset = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(filenames=['/content/mydata.bin']*7000, record_bytes=RAW_N*4)
raw_dataset = raw_dataset.map(decode_and_prepare)
```

**Train model *without* caching and iterating beforehand**:

```py
total_data_entries = len(list(raw_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (x, y))))
train_ds = raw_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=total_data_entries).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((400,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(train_ds, epochs=5)
```

```
Epoch 1/5
875/875 [==============================] - 4s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1425
Epoch 2/5
875/875 [==============================] - 4s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0841
Epoch 3/5
875/875 [==============================] - 4s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0840
Epoch 4/5
875/875 [==============================] - 4s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0840
Epoch 5/5
875/875 [==============================] - 4s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0840
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fc41be037d0>
```

**Training model *with* caching but *no* iterating**:

```py
total_data_entries = len(list(raw_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (x, y))))
train_ds = raw_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=total_data_entries).cache().batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((400,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(train_ds, epochs=5)
```

```
Epoch 1/5
875/875 [==============================] - 4s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1428
Epoch 2/5
875/875 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0841
Epoch 3/5
875/875 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0840
Epoch 4/5
875/875 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0840
Epoch 5/5
875/875 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0840
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fc41fa87810>
```

**Training model *with* caching and iterating**:

```py
total_data_entries = len(list(raw_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (x, y))))
train_ds = raw_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=total_data_entries).cache().batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
_ = list(train_ds.as_numpy_iterator()) # iterate dataset beforehand
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((400,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(train_ds, epochs=5)
```

```
Epoch 1/5
875/875 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1427
Epoch 2/5
875/875 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0841
Epoch 3/5
875/875 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0840
Epoch 4/5
875/875 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0840
Epoch 5/5
875/875 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0840
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fc41ac9c850>
```

Conclusion: The caching and the prior iteration of the dataset seem to have an effect on training, but in this example only 7000 files were used.

Comment: Thanks for you experiment. I reproduced it by replacing 7000 by 100'000 and I've found that calling `cache()` actually matters.

Comment: Yes. Did you also iterate beforehand? Notice any difference there?

Comment: Yes, I was just writing about it. So I can understand, iterating the training ds beforehand will preload the cache before the first epoch. Cool. I'm evaluating the role of `.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` in your experiment. In my original settings, `cache()` only shows effects if I remove `.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)`

Comment: all data in one epoch is saved to memory? So if one iteration of dataset does not fit in memory cache() wouldn't work?